# "ambiguous subscript" when trying to return an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm looking to extract sub-arrays in Swift 4 and running into unexpected difficulties.

The following trivial cases work as expected:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c","x","y","z"]
array1[2...3]  // returns ["c","x"], as it should
```

as does the following variation:

```
let m=2
let n=3
array1[m...n]  // returns ["c","x"], as it should
```

But if I try to create a function around this, I get an error message `ambiguous subscript with base type 'Array<Any>' and index type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'`:

```
func arrayTake(arrayIn: Array<Any>) -> Array<Any> {
    return arrayIn[2...3]
}     // no good
```

And of course, the following form, which is closer to what I actually want to do, fails with the same error message:

```
func arrayTake(m: Int, n: Int, arrayIn: Array<Any>) -> Array<Any> {
    return arrayIn[m...n]
}     // no good
```

I have seen other questions here about ambiguous subscripts but have not been able to translate the answers there into a solution to my problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are getting such error because you are trying to return an [ArraySlice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice) instead of the expected `Array<Any>`:

> Slices Are Views onto Arrays

You may want to convert such slice using a dedicated Array constructor:

```
func arrayTake(m: Int, n: Int, arrayIn: Array<Any>) -> Array<Any> {
    return Array<Any>(arrayIn[m...n])
}
```

Moreover, please note that long-term storage of `ArraySlice` is discouraged, a slice holds a reference to the entire storage of a larger array, not just to the portion it presents, even after the original array’s lifetime ends. Long-term storage of a slice may therefore prolong the lifetime of elements that are no longer otherwise accessible, which can appear to be memory and object leakage.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is Datatype mismatch.

`array1[2...3]` This statement does not return Array it returns ArraySlice a special DataType (struct) for this kind of array operation.

So you can solve this by two way.

Change return type to ArraySlice

```
func arrayTake(m: Int, n: Int, arrayIn: Array<Any>) -> ArraySlice<Any> 
{   
    return arrayIn[m...n] 
}
```

OR

Convert ArraySlice to Array

```
func arrayTake(m: Int, n: Int, arrayIn: Array<Any>) -> Array<Any> {  
    return Array(arrayIn[m...n])    
}
```

Both will print same output but keep in mind that they are not same:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c","x","y","z"]
let result = arrayTake(m: 2, n: 3, arrayIn: array1)

print(result) //["c","x"], as it should
```

Check this for more detail: https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/arrayslice-in-swift-4e18522ab4e4

Comment: Clearly a good answer, thank you. I gave the checkmark to @Andrea Mugnaini only because he got in first.